# What is the maximum height of a dwarf in Warhammer Fantasy universe?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

I'm curious about the maximum height for a dwarf in the Warhammer universe. I have looked in several places online and been unable to find an answer.

Comment: [Snorri Nosebitter](http://whfb.lexicanum.com/wiki/Snorri_Nosebiter) is really tall for a dwarf. It's mentioned in one of the Gotrek and Felix novels. I can't remember which one though. Felix comments on it or maybe it's one of his internal monolouges, but it's somthing like _Snorri is tall for a dwarf_.

Comment: thanks just wanting to know if they can be like nearly as tall as man but information is rather hard to come by haha

Comment: A very tall dwarf can be as tall as an short-to-average height man. But I think that's about as close as they can get.

Comment: so is average man around 5"9 and thank you u have been very helpful

Comment: No problem at all.

Comment: n is that about right for average height ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From **Page 24** of the *[Warhammer FRP Rulebook](http://khorne.ru/2nd/wfrp_web/Core.pdf)*:

> Dwarf:
>   Male - 4’4”+1d10”
>   Female - 4’2”+1d10"

Therefore, the tallest a Dwarf Man can be is no more than 5'2" and a Dwarf Woman can be no more than 5'0".

Comment: @markusthemad if you're happy with this answer, you might want to mark it as accepted.

Comment: how do i do that :)

Comment: I believe, as the question asker, that you can see a tick or something underneath the upvote / downvote buttons? Clicking the tick marks the answer as accepted.